# Torrent cannot complete on transmission-remote in docker container due to continuous deletion of data

Tags: docker, vpn, bittorrent, transmission, transmission-daemon

transmission-remote is running in a docker container with good internet connection, downloading a file with sufficient seeders. As the torrent approaches 99% completion, the download speed will slow, and then the completion rate will be reduced to 98% or even 97%, before climbing back up. Similarly, the total data will fluctuate between 4.83 and 4.88GB. This problem previously occurred at lower levels of completion, but was mitigated by removing other torrents. This increased the download rate, but didn't stop data from disappearing. The data is stored in a host volume mapped to a container directory.

What could cause the data to disappear, and how can this be prevented?

Not sure this is relevant, but the transmission container connects to the internet through another container running nordvpn.

transmission-remote version 3.00
docker version 20.10.10

Comment: Can you explain what "dissapear" means? AFAIK, once a torrent receives data and verifies that it is valid, it should never delete it unless instructed to do so.

Comment: That is my understanding as well. I do not know whether data is actually deleted, or whether transmission is failing to accurately report what data is present in the first place. What I can see is as described in the post, that the amount of downloaded data will appear to fluctuate, sometimes increasing, sometimes decreasing.